# Is it possible to get the description value of a defined Symbol in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have a symbol such as `const sym = Symbol('foo');`. Now, is there a way to get the value `foo` from that symbol without relying on string manipulations?

I expected `sym.toString()` to return `'foo'` but it returns `Symbol(foo)`.

### Update

I settled with this hacky solution, until I find a better one :)

```
const key = Symbol.keyFor(sym) || (sym = sym.toString(), sym.substring(7, sym.length - 1));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the [`Symbol.keyFor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/keyFor). But it only works with the globally registered symbols

```
const works = Symbol.for('foo');
const key1 = Symbol.keyFor(works); // "foo"

const doesNotWork = Symbol('foo');
const key2 = Symbol.keyFor(doesNotWork); // undefined
```

I'm guessing that the private symbols do this by design. You could always monkey patch it:

```
const patched = Symbol('foo');
patched.key = 'foo';
```

Comment: i get an `undefined` ...

Comment: @TheReason an undefined what?

Comment: `key` is `undefined`

Comment: Actually, the docs says that, in order to use `Symbol.keyFor`, one must use `Symbol.for` to register a global Symbol. In the proposed case, the Symbol is not global. It *is* a solution though....

Comment: i suppose it should be `let sym = Symbol.for('Hello everybody!');
     Symbol.keyFor(sym); //   'Hello everybody!'`